# How can I determine the original directory that an alias points to?

Tags: ruby

I'm working with a directory that's an alias on Mac OS, with Ruby. This is a folder that points to another folder. How can I determine the original directory that this alias points to?

In one of my Jenkins jobs, there is an alias called `lastStable`, which points to the latest stable build folder:

[image]

```
path = /Users/steve/.Jenkins/jobs/MyApp/lastStable
```

`lastStable` actually points to a folder called `2013-08-06_10_50_49`.

How can I get this info dynamically in Ruby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`File.realpath` resolves symlinks.

You could do:

```
File.realpath '/usr/bin/ruby'
#=> "/usr/bin/ruby1.9.3"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `readlink` method:

```
File.readlink(path)
```

Comment: readlink's output was "10", which is another folder that is actually another alias. So it apparently is not recursive. realpath however did the evaluation correctly.